# textView not getting set from another view controller (using Singleton class)

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, singleton, xcode4.3

I have a textViewController class. I want to set(basically update) the corresponding textView's content from another view controller which I am pushing over the present textViewController. The way I thought I could do this was to have a shared singleton class and have a string property there to contain the text. I have been using the singleton for storing some other content as well and it worked fine till now.

---

But the text variable in singleton class doesn't hold the content I pass to it from the second view controller and hence the textViewController, after popping the second view controller, displays the old text even after reappearing. I am updating the textView in its viewWillAppear method which is getting called but shows old text content on NSLogging.
What am I missing here? Please suggest a solution, stuck at it for a long time now.

Comment: Please post the relevant source code. You may have run into a memory management issue. Also - based on the problem you've described, it sounds like you should be using a delegate pattern rather than a singleton.

Comment: I am setting the singleton property like this: [MySingleton sharedSingleton].text = newwiki; inside viewDidDisappear of second view controller where newwiki is my string content. And in viewWillAppear of textViewController I have: self.textView.text= [MySingleton sharedSingleton].text;

Comment: are you certain that newwiki is a valid reference when viewDidDisappear is called?

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't know why the singleton property doesn't hold its value assigned to it by a view which is being popped off. Maybe, its this that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Declaration

Firstly, declare the `NSString` in your app delegate `.h` file. It should look something like this:

```
//YourAppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourAppDelegate : NSObject < UIApplicationDelegate >
{
    NSString *sharedString; //WE ADDED THIS
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sharedString; //AND THIS
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SomeViewController *viewController;

@end
```

Now you want to synthesize the object so that the accessor and mutator methods are made for you. This means you don't have to write the `setSharedString:` and `getSharedString` methods - we can simply access and mutate the object by making a reference to it. This is how we synthesize it in the `.m` file:

```
//YourAppDelegate.m
@synthesize sharedString;
```

### Assigning a Value

When you want to assign a value to `sharedString` from another class, you must first retrieve the active instance of your application delegate:

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

The `appDelegate` object here is your running app delegate instance. To access the `sharedString` `NSString` object in the delegate and assign a value, we'd do this:

```
appDelegate.sharedString = @"some string we want to assign";
```

For the duration of our application's runtime, "**some string we want to assign**" is now stored in `sharedString` in our app delegate.

### Retrieving the Value

You'll want to retrieve the value at some point. To do this, again we'll have to get the running instance of our application delegate:

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Once we have the running instance, we can then access the `sharedString` object stored inside it:

```
NSString *retrievedString = appDelegate.sharedString;
```

From this point, `retrievedString` now holds the value "**some string we want to assign**".

#### Note:

> *Everywhere I mention `YourAppDelegate`, I am referring to your app delegate - the app delegate you have in your project. It'll be related to your project name (look for the file).*

Comment: I dont know how it is going to work. I tried retrieving strings but they all show to be null.

Comment: I have rewritten the answer and have tried to be very thorough. If you don't understand now, there's not much more I can do! Good luck

Comment: +1 nice and complete answer - isn't everyone using ARC by now, though?

Comment: Thanks a ton. I really appreciate your help. But I have figured out that the viewWillAppear starts to execute even before viewDidDisappear ends. I am doing file reading stuff in viewDidDisappear at the end of which I update the textView which I think is taking a bit of time. So viewWillAppear is done getting executed even before new content is available. I need to figure out a way around. If you have any suggestions, do share. Thanks again.

Comment: viewDidLoad is called only once. Whereas I need to update textView each time the view appears.

Answer (score 0):

How your NSString property for your Text-Variable is defined? Is it a "weak"?

Comment: I have defined it as (nonatomic, readwrite). Should it be something else?